# Whenever i pressed any of those post buttons, only the first on the list will be updated instead of the speacific button that i pressed

Tags: php, mysql, forms, button, while-loop

```
<?php

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimonial ORDER BY id DESC");
 //This block grabs the whole list for viewing
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
         $id = $row['id'];
         $name = $row['name'];
         $comment = $row['comment'];
         $visibility = $row['visibility'];
         $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row['date_added']));}

 This section is for buttons if i press the button named update it should update the field named "visibility" to approved and if i press the button named update1 it should update the field named "visibility" to hide

 if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        $a =  addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['update']));
        $selected = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonial` WHERE id = '$id'");
        $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($selected);   
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `testimonial` SET `visibility` = 'approved' WHERE id = '$id'");
    }
 if(isset($_POST['update1']))
    {
        $a =  addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['update1']));
        $selected = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonial` WHERE id = '$id'");
        $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($selected);       
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `testimonial` SET `visibility` = 'hide' WHERE name='$name'");
    }
```

this line is for the header of the table where i started the loop

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimonial");
    echo '<form onSubmit="return validateForm()" action="testimonials.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

        <div align="center">
        <table width="1273" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
          <tr>
            <th width="119" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><strong>ID</strong></th>
            <th width="88" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><strong>User</strong></th>
            <th width="629" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><div align="center"><strong>Content</strong></div></th>
            <th width="107" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><strong>Status</strong></th>
            <th width="111" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><strong>Date Added</strong></th>
            <th width="111" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><strong>Action</strong></th>
            <th width="111" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><strong>Action</strong></th>
          </tr>';
```

This condition is to update the table field name "visibility" to posted if the visibility is equal to approved and if the other button is pressed it should update the table field "visibility" to not posted

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo'<tr>';
        echo'<th width="119" scope="col">'.$row['id'].'</th>';
        echo'<th width="88" scope="col">'.$row['name'].'</th>';
        echo'<th width="629" scope="col"><div align="center">'.$row['comment'].'</div></th>';
        echo'<th width="107" scope="col">'.$row['visibility'].'</th>';
        echo'<th width="111" scope="col">'.$row['date_added'].'</th>';

        $activ= $row['visibility'];
    if ($activ=='approved'){ $visibility="Posted";} if ($activ=='hide'){$visibility="Not Posted";}
        echo '<th width="107" scope="col">'.$visibility.'</th>';
        echo'<th width="111" scope="col"><button type="submit" name="update" class="button" value='.$row['id'].'>Post</button><button type="submit" name="update1" class="button" value='.$row['id'].'>Unpost</button></th>';

        echo'</tr>';

    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop in first code block has issue. You are trying to store the ID in the variable `id`. But you are overwriting the value of `id` upon each iteration.

Assume, you have 10 records with id `1 2 3 ... 10`

On first iteration, you are storing the value `10` (since SQL as DESC) in `id`

On second iteration, you are overwriting the value by `9`.

So the end of the iteration, your `id` will hold nothing but `1`

This `id` with value `1` is supplied for `UPDATE` query, that's why everytime your first row/record is updated.

I am little bit confused about your logic.

Try this :

Since, you are assigning ID as value for each `submit` button, upon form submission, try to fetch the value of your submit button like `$my_id = $_POST['update']`

Use this `$my_id` in your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It finally worked!!!! i used $my_id = $_POST['update'] :D